# YouTube Asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, youtube, youtube-api

I've been messing with the YouTube Javascript API recently, but I've run into a problem (as always!).

I need a function to return an array of information about a video:

```
 [0: Title, 1: Description, 2: Publish Date, 3: Thumbnail URL]
```

The function takes the id of a video then does a video.list with that id. Here is that function:

```
function getVidInfo(VidId){
    var vidRequest;
    var vidRequestResponse;
    var returnArray = new Array(4);

    vidRequest = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        id: VidId
    });
    vidRequest.execute(function(response){
        if(response.pageInfo.totalResults != 0) {
            returnArray[0] = response.result.items[0].snippet.title;
            returnArray[1] = response.result.items[0].snippet.description;
            returnArray[2] = response.result.items[0].snippet.publishedAt;
            //Check for HD thumbnail
            if (response.result.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url){
                returnArray[3] = response.result.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url
            }
            else {
                returnArray[3] = response.result.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.standard.url;
            }
            console.log(returnArray); //Will log desired return array
        }
    });
    return returnArray; //Not returning desired array
}
```

As you can see from the comments the array is being set correctly however it's not returning that value.

**What have I tried?**

- Using an external variable being set from a function called in `vidRequest.execute()`
- Returning from `vidRequest.execute()`
- Putting response into a variable and then assigning the array (Gave me an error about pageInfo being `undefined`)

**Notes**

- It appears to be an asynchronous problem
- I need to keep `getVidInfo()`
- It definetely gets called when the Google API loads
- It appears to work on the initial load, but a refresh breaks it
- All info is logged to the console at the moment

**Full Code**

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>YT Test</title>
    <!--My Scripts-->
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Load google api last-->
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*test.js*

```
var apiKey = "[YOUR API KEY]"; //I did set this to my API key
var latestVidUrl;
var request;
var vidId;
var vidInfo;

function googleApiClientReady() {
    console.log("Google api loaded");
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
        request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: 'id',
            channelId: 'UCOYWgypDktXdb-HfZnSMK6A',
            maxResults: 1,
            type: 'video',
            order: 'date'
        });
        request.execute(function(response) {
            if(response.pageInfo.totalResults != 0) {
                vidId = response.result.items[0].id.videoId;
                //console.log(vidId);
                vidInfo = getVidInfo(vidId);
                console.log(vidInfo);
            }
        });
    }); 
}

function getEmbedCode(id){
    var baseURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
    return baseURL + id.toString();
}

function getVidInfo(VidId){
    var vidRequest;
    var vidRequestResponse;
    var returnArray = new Array(4);

    vidRequest = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        id: VidId
    });
    vidRequest.execute(function(response){
        if(response.pageInfo.totalResults != 0) {
            returnArray[0] = response.result.items[0].snippet.title;
            returnArray[1] = response.result.items[0].snippet.description;
            returnArray[2] = response.result.items[0].snippet.publishedAt;
            //Check for HD thumbnail
            if (response.result.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url){
                returnArray[3] = response.result.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url
            }
            else {
                returnArray[3] = response.result.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.standard.url;
            }
            console.log(returnArray); //Will log desired return array
        }
    });
    return returnArray; //Not returning desired array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are returning returnArray when it might not be handled yet.  To clarify what I mean, Even though you have `return returnArray` at the end, the actual request is still be handled, but the code keeps going anyway.  So when it finally gets a response, and handles the code, it writes it correctly to the log, but the function has already returned returnArray earlier.  Without testing if this works, you could probably just add a polling function to wait until returnArray is not null, as long as you never expect it to be null.  Maybe something like:

```
while(returnArray == null) {
    ; }
return returnArray;
```

I'll just edit this to clarify what I mean:

```
function getVidInfo(VidId){
var vidRequest;
var vidRequestResponse;
var returnArray = new Array(4);

vidRequest = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
    part: 'snippet',
    id: VidId
});
vidRequest.execute(function(response){
    if(response.pageInfo.totalResults != 0) {
        returnArray[0] = response.result.items[0].snippet.title;
        returnArray[1] = response.result.items[0].snippet.description;
        returnArray[2] = response.result.items[0].snippet.publishedAt;
        //Check for HD thumbnail
        if (response.result.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url){
            returnArray[3] = response.result.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url
        }
        else {
            returnArray[3] = response.result.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.standard.url;
        }
        console.log(returnArray); //Will log desired return array
    }
});

while(returnArray == null) {    //Create busy loop to wait for value
    ; }

return returnArray;
```

}

Comment: I tried the while thing, it didn't work. The trouble with the polling function is I need to call a 'return', but if I do so it returns in the polled function, not the `getVidInfo`

Comment: @EverlessDrop41 I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but when I said "function", I meant it more as just an extra addition.  After the vidRequest.execute function, you want to wait until returnArray has been initialized before returning it.  So after vidRequest.execute function, right after the `)};`, add the while loop.  I do know that you are running into an asynchronous logic problem, and the best way I can think of right now is waiting until returnArray is initialized to return it.

Comment: @EverlessDrop41 Another way I have seen people handle this problem is calling another function in the response to handle the return value, but it is a little tricky to implement given the structure of your code.

Comment: @EverlessDrop41 here, try this:
while (returnArray == ",,,") { ; } return returnArray;

Answer (score 1):

The `execute` function is asynchronous; thus, it hasn't completed by the time you're returning the `returnArray` array, and so an empty array gets sent back instead (if you have the console open you'll see that's the case, where the empty array comes back and gets logged, and then a second or so later the logging within the callback happens). This is one of the biggest obstacles in asynchronous programming, and with the YouTube APIs it used to be that the only way around it was to nest your callbacks in multiple levels (i.e. don't have it as a separate function that returns a value) -- or what I like to affectionately term callback inception. So you could go that route (where you move all the code from your `getVidInfo` function up into the callback from the request where you get the ID), but that will get very messy ... and luckily the API client very recently introduced features that make solving this problem a whole lot easier -- the gapi client is now [Promises/A+ compliant](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2014/10/promises-in-google-apis-javascript.html).

So basically, all request objects can now return a Promise object instead of utilize a callback function, and you can chain them all together so they all get processed and resolved in the order you need them to (note that this promise object does very slightly change the json structure of the response packet, where parameters such as `pageInfo` are children of the `result` attribute rather than siblings -- you'll see in the sample code below what I mean). This will also greatly simplify your code, so you could do something like this:

```
var apiKey = "[YOUR API KEY]";  

function googleApiClientReady() {
    console.log("Google api loaded");
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: 'id',
            channelId: 'UCOYWgypDktXdb-HfZnSMK6A',
            maxResults: 1,
            type: 'video',
            order: 'date'
        }).then(function(response) {
            if(response.result.pageInfo.totalResults != 0) { // note how pageInfo is now a child of response.result ... this is because the promise object is structured a bit differently
                return response.result.items[0].id.videoId;
            }
        }).then(function(vidId) {
                return gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
                        part: 'snippet',
                        id: vidId
                });
        }).then(function(response) { 
                var returnArray=Array();
                if(response.result.pageInfo.totalResults != 0) {
                        returnArray[0] = response.result.items[0].snippet.title;
                        returnArray[1] = response.result.items[0].snippet.description;
                        returnArray[2] = response.result.items[0].snippet.publishedAt;
                        //Check for HD thumbnail
                        if (response.result.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url){
                                returnArray[3] = response.result.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url;
                        }
                        else {
                                returnArray[3] = response.result.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.standard.url;
                        }
                }
                return returnArray;
        }).then(function(returnArray) {
                console.log(returnArray);
        });
  });
}
```

This architecture could also greatly help with error handling, as you could construct additional anonymous functions to pass as the 2nd argument in each `then` call to be executed when the API throws an error of some sort. Because each of the calls returns a promise, you can, in the final call, use `returnArray` however you need, and it will wait until all the pieces are resolved before executing.

Comment: Do you have to return a value to call `.then()`?

Comment: It's not required but it's useful. In the Promises architecture, the 'then' method will be executed when the previous promise is resolved, and it takes two functions as arguments ... the first is executed if the promise resolved successfully, the second if it threw errors. The reason you return a value inside one promise's success function is so that subsequent success functions can access data from previous ones.

Comment: Ok, as I would like to keep `getVidInfo()` as a function I create a boolean value called `canReturn`, with a `while(!canReturn){;} return  returnArray` there's a `.then()` after `vidRequest.execute` but I get an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: then() is not a property of execute, but of the request itself ... so it would be vidRequest.then() -- however, you don't want to use a promise with a while loop, as promises get rid of the need for them. If you want to keep your function (is there a reason?), then to get it to work you'd still have to nest the logic of that function inside the vidRequest's callback somehow ... if you try to rely on a while loop, imagine what would happen if there were a network error? the array would never be populated, and the function would never return, thus crashing your app.

Comment: Thanks, I need to keep `getVidInfo()` as I plan to use it to get info on multiple videos (all of a users emails) which are then displayed on the webpage. Do you have any idea how I could keep the function?