# Calling YouTube API request in Angular JS service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, youtube-api

I'm having issues creating a Youtube Service which does a simple search based on a 'search term'. What I would like to do is allow controllers to call into my youtube service (i.e. searchVideo("dogs")) and get a video-id, as a string, back.

At this time, I'm noticing that the requestVideoId is being returned before the request can finish executing. Being unfamiliar with JS, I would like an example of how I can have my searchVideo() function return the requestVideoId correctly (after the request has finished).

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var serviceId = 'youtubeService';
angular.module('app').factory(serviceId, ['common', youtubeService]);

function youtubeService(common) {
    var service = {
        searchVideo: searchVideo
    };

    return service;

    function searchVideo(searchText) {
        var requestVideoId = "";
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            q: searchText,
            part: 'snippet'
        });

        request.execute(function(response) {
            var responseList = response.result;
            console.log(responseList.items[0].id.videoId);
            requestVideoId = responseList.items[0].id.videoId;
        });

        console.log(requestVideoId);
        return requestVideoId;
    }
}
})();
```

I've checked this question... [YouTube Asynchronous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131951/youtube-asynchronous-function) ... But I want to keep the searchVideo() function. I could be missing something. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`searchVideo` should return a `promise` that gets resolved in future. Something like:

```
 function searchVideo(searchText) {
        var defer=$q.defer();
        var requestVideoId = "";
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            q: searchText,
            part: 'snippet'
        });

        request.execute(function(response) {
            var responseList = response.result;
            console.log(responseList.items[0].id.videoId);
            requestVideoId = responseList.items[0].id.videoId;
            defer.resolve(requestVideoId);
        });

        console.log(requestVideoId);
        return defer.promise;
    }
```

Now you can use the promise api, to register a callback when the promise is resolved:

`youtubeService.searchVideo('test')
     .then(function(requestVideoId) { // can access the id here});`

Learn about [what promises are](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and [how promises work in Angular](https://thinkster.io/egghead/promises/).

Comment: Thank you for the awesome answer and direction. This worked and helped me get on my way to understanding Angular. Thank you!